# Using both group and color in plotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I am trying to plot a number of dimensions in `r` using plotly - is it possible to use both `color` and `group` parameters on factor variables to have a line that changes color?

Example:

```
grp <- c(letters[c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2)])
a <- c(1,2,3,4,2,3,4,5)
b <- c(1,3,5,6,1,2,4,4)
lvl <- c(1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2)

df <- data.frame(grp, a, b, lvl)
```

When plotting this using `ggplot()` I am able to create the desired effect as below, with `grp` as to define each line and `lvl` to define the color of sections of the line:

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = a, y = b, group = grp, color = lvl)) + geom_line() + geom_point()
```

[image]

However, when I then call `ggplotly()` the line gets grouped *and* colored by `lvl`.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I'm searching for the same function. It seems that group and color is plotly kryptonite. 
So far my only solution is to make a column of color codes and use that to define the colors of the markers:

```
library(scales)
library(plotly)

grp <- c(letters[c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2)])
a <- c(1,2,3,4,2,3,4,5)
b <- c(1,3,5,6,1,2,4,4)
lvl <- c(1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2)
df <- data.frame(grp, a, b, lvl)

Palette <- data.frame(lvl = unique(df$lvl), color = brewer_pal("seq",palette = "Reds",direction = -1)(length(unique(df$lvl))), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df <- merge(x = df, y = Palette, by = "lvl")

p <- plot_ly(df, x = a, y = b, group = grp, mode = "markers+lines", marker = list(color = color, size = 8), line = list(color = "black", width = 2))
p
```

however this trick is very cumbersome and does not work with "line" that only takes a single color input [and looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fi3xT.png). HOWEVER if you do not give an input to the "line" it displays two different colors that you have no control over. [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nN6jd.png)

Answer (score 5):

I was trying to do the same thing and there is now an official way : you need to add a `group_by` statement before `plot_ly` (see https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/418)

```
grp <- c(letters[c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2)])
a <- c(1,2,3,4,2,3,4,5)
b <- c(1,3,5,6,1,2,4,4)
lvl <- c(1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2)

df <- data.frame(grp, a, b, lvl)
df %>% group_by(grp) %>% plot_ly(x = a, y = b, mode = "markers+lines", color = lvl)
```