# ggplotly - mismatching when using color aesthetics

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly

I'm using ggplotly to convert a ggplot object to interactive plotly. The problem I'm encountering is when the ggplot object is using an associated color aesthetic. 
For example, using the following dummy example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

datetime.data = seq.POSIXt(from = ISOdatetime(2017, 10, 1, 0, 0, 0), to = ISOdate(2017, 10, 15, 23, 0, 0), by = 'hour')
date.data <- as.Date(datetime.data)
x.data <- as.numeric(strftime(datetime.data, format="%H")) * 60 + as.numeric(strftime(datetime.data, format="%M"))
y.data1 <- as.numeric(date.data) + sin(x.data)
color.data <- runif(length(x.data), 0, 10)

df <- data.frame(Datetime = datetime.data, Date = date.data, X = x.data, Y = y.data1, Color = color.data)

# continuous color scale
gg <- ggplot(df, aes(x=X, y=Y, group=Date)) + geom_line(aes(color=Color)) + ggtitle("Continuous")
print(gg)

ggly <- ggplotly(gg)
print(ggly)

# discrete color scale
df[, "Color"] <- round(df[, "Color"])
df[, "Color"] <- as.factor(df[, "Color"])

gg <- ggplot(df, aes(x=X, y=Y, group=Date)) + geom_line(aes(color=Color)) + ggtitle("Discrete")
print(gg)

ggly <- ggplotly(gg)
print(ggly)
```

And the results using ggplot and the corresponding plotly object:

[image: ggplot - continuous color scale]

[image: ggplotly - continuous color scale]

[image: ggplot - discrete color scale]

[image: ggplotly - discrete color scale]

With so basic example, I'm thinking it could be related to some version bug? I'm using updated packages, although a development version of ggplot [using `devtools::install_github('hadley/ggplot2')`] as recommended when using ggplotly(). My package and R versions:

```
> packageVersion("ggplot2")
 ‘2.2.1.9000’

> packageVersion("plotly")
 ‘4.7.1’

> R.version$version.string            
" R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21) "
```

Comment: Sorry, what's the problem?

Comment: shouldn't be the plotly chart identical to the ggplot chart but just with the added interactivity? In the continuous case, there is no visualization at all but the data is there because when I hover the mouse over the chart I can get the interaction. In the discrete case, the plotted lines are all mixed and do not correspond the groups created by Date (as in the ggplot chart).

Comment: I found this [stackoverfow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35283743/using-both-group-and-color-in-plotly) to be an equivalent problem but related only to plotly and not ggplotly(). Using the suggested approach in the answer (using group_by()), I'm able to plot the plotly chart correctly using both group and color aesthetic. However, I'd like to be able to create the ggplot and then use ggplotly to convert it.